# How to get the return value of VBScript to automation anywhere?

Tags: vb6, rpa, automationanywhere

Here's the sample code that I try to work on, and it throws an error code 1025. I try to search something that may solve that issue, but no luck in finding any helpful information.

I just want to return the value "num3" to Automation anywhere. I'm not sure if I use the right command line for returning the value (`WScript.StdOut.Write`). If I use a wrong command please teach me or point to a link where I can learn the write command line.

```
Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()

num1 = 2
num2 = 5
num3 = num1 + num2


WScript.StdOut.Write(num3) ' Is this the right command ?

End Sub
```

How to get the return value of VBScript to automation anywhere?

Comment: This looks like VB6 code. If that's the case, Wscriot object will not be available, you need to create an instance first

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes its a VB6 code, so the WScript.StdOut.Write is correct? I just need to create an instance ?

Comment: So you want to write toe stdout using VB6?  Are you trying to make a command line tool in vb6?

Comment: What do you mean by "automation" ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add reference to `Windows Script Host Object Model` type library in `Project->References...` menu, then save your project `.vbp` files and open it in Notepad and append following two lines at the end:

```
[VBCompiler]
LinkSwitches=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Save the `.vbp` file and re-open the project in VB6 IDE and paste the following code in `Form1`:

```
Option Explicit

Private StdOut                  As TextStream

Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    With New FileSystemObject
        Set StdOut = .GetStandardStream(1)
    End With

    num1 = 2
    num2 = 5
    num3 = num1 + num2

    StdOut.WriteLine num3
End Sub
```

Compile project to `Project1.exe` and start it from command prompt to get something like this in the console:

```
C:> Project1.exe
7
```

. . . and then `Form1` is shown, so the application will not terminate immediately.

Try to put your code in `Sub Main` in standard `.bas` module w/ no forms at all for a truly console VB6 application.

Here is a zip of the project above: [StdOutTest.zip](https://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/StdOutTest.zip)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little bit ambiguous, but I will try to answer it the best I can

## If you want to output a number (exit code)

Just do this,

```
' https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6e76731-8e3b-465f-9d5a-12c6498d6b6c/how-to-return-exit-code-from-vb6-form?forum=winforms
Private Declare Sub ExitProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uExitCode As Long)
' (then in some function)
ExitProcess 666666 ' whatever number to output to the other process
```

## If you want to output to StdOut (console)

[image: Nirsoft screenshot]

This is a little trickier.  VB6 isn't natively designed to work this way. However, there is a barely-known workaround. [Initially designed by Nirsoft, who managed to do the impossible](http://www.nirsoft.net/vb/console.html), I modified and slightly optimised (ironically, for CLI usage) their code, which is now available [in my repo](https://github.com/TAbdiukov/AMC_patcher-CLI). Here is how to deploy it.

1. Clone the repo,
2. Copy `CLI.bas` to your project, then add `CLI.bas` to your project. Now you can use the CLI functions. For example

```
CLI.setup ' required line, to set up variables
CLI.send "some text -> "
CLI.SetTextColour CLI.FOREGROUND_RED OR CLI.FOREGROUND_GREEN OR CLI.FOREGROUND_INTENSITY ' for Orange and Intensive text, need to use OR, not AND
CLI.sendln "Orange foobar!"
CLI.sendln "maybe another line, why not?"
```

3. Now you can use these functions if your code. *Make sure to call `CLI.setup` first.* I'd recommend for the first time, just test the functionality in `Form1_Load()`
4. Compile your executable via VB6 suite, but this isn't the end of the story
5. Your compiled app has to be patched to work in command-line mode. To do so, `CD` into `AMC_patcher-CLI` folder you called and perform

`amc "C:/Projects/My supa CLI project/Project1.exe" 3`

Where
`"C:/Projects/My supa CLI project/Project1.exe"` - Is the path to your app EXE

Or alternatively for the patching step, use [Nirsoft's original GUI patcher implementation](http://www.nirsoft.net/vb/console.zip). It is less scalable, but just as sturdy

Comment: thanks for the answer :) Ill try that :) thank you sir

Comment: @ Luna All good mate! Happen you have any questions, let me know! I probably had too much fun with this back in the day :)

Comment: Valiant effort but the undocumented `LinkSwitches=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` saves all the patch-work modifying the PE header post compilation and the stream from `GetStandardStream` on `FileSystemObject` saves all the gory API details.

Comment: @ wqw Possibly. I'm glad I found out about `LinkSwitches=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE ` Today. But wouldn't attaching extra library just for the correct compilation a bit an overkill and make the resulting EXE unreasonably beefy?

Comment: @tabdiukov Which extra library are you talking about? "Windows Scripting Host" is *not* staticly linked into the executable and it's a built-in Windows component so no need to redistribute too. Btw, it's  possible to tweak `link.exe` switches even more to "slim" the final executable further.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answers given, please note that...

```
Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer
```

... actually means *(except if a `Defxxx` statement is used elsewhere and left out here)*

```
Dim num1 As Variant
Dim num2 As Variant
Dim num3 As Integer
```

... which probably is not what you think it means.